# How to rotate with OrbitControls, without limits

Tags: three.js

Right now i'm using orbit controls, and i can only rotate 180 degrees in the up-and-down direction.  In another direction i can rotate forever, i think it is the z direction.  Anyways, how can i make it completely limiteless for all rotation directions?

here's my code now, i tried it with and without infinity:

```
this.scene_threeD = new THREE.Scene();
this.camera_threeD = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, width_threeD / height_threeD, 0.1, 1000 );
this.renderer_threeD = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: threeDCanvas,
                               preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
                               antialias: true });
this.renderer_threeD.setSize( width_threeD, height_threeD);
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera_threeD, this.renderer_threeD.domElement);
        controls.maxPolarAngle = Infinity;
        controls.minPolarAngle = -Infinity;
        controls.maxAzimuthAngle = Infinity;
        controls.minAzimuthAngle=-Infinity;
        controls.update();
```

Comment: There's [`THREE.TrackballControls()`](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=controls#misc_controls_trackball) in three.js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with an "orbital camera" is that (by definition) it always tries to keep the camera "up" pointing *upwards*. This means the camera orientation is *undefined* when you are looking straight up or down. That is why three.js implements a makeSafe() method that keeps the polar angle just within a +/- 90 degrees angle.

If you were to remove this limitation, you would probably see the camera instantly flip directions when passing the 90 degrees angle (or worse). This is generally undesired behaviour in an application.

**To sum things up: if you want limitless rotation, you don't want an *orbital* camera. This is not a technical but a conceptual limitation.**

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, it now makes sense. Do you have any resources on rotating the object instead?